# iOS MPMoviePlayerController does not play audio after the app was relaunched on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-player

I'm trying to use MPMoviePlayerController to create an audio player without having to implement my own scrubbing and play/pause button.

I have code that records audio into NSData and saves it to disk. The method below tests audio by playing it with the MPMoviePlayerController.

The code below works (plays audio, it is heard) if I execute the method immediately after recording is done. It also works if I press home button, then return to the app.

However, when **I kill the app and restart, or hit "run" from xCode, I do not hear any audio.** Here are the symptoms:

- The code below lists that the **NSData exists** on disk and has length
- The **path** to NSData **is the same both** times
- NSData is **kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC** format
- The media player displays **correct duration**
- Media player's **scrubber moves** from start to finish
- Speaker **volume is set** to maximum in both cases.
- **No audio** is heard after the app was killed and restarted.

**What could be causing my MPMoviePlayerController to not provide any audio upon app relaunch?** I'm writing the audio length into the file's extended attributes, could this be messing with the "Playability" of the file?

```
-(void)testPlayback:(AudioNote*)note
{
    NSString* path = [note filepath];
    if(note == nil || path.length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

   //file exists, and data exists on disk in both cases
    NSString* exists = ([note fileExists]? @"YES":@"NO");
    NSUInteger length = note.fileData.length;

    DLog(@"Playing note (exists: %@, data length:%i), duration: %.2f",exists,length,note.durationSeconds);

    self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];


    [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Comment: Simulator only? Or a device?

Comment: Tested on actual iPad